# Tikz Block DIagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me into making this block diagram made with power point in tikz?

[image: [1]:]

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! Drawing the diagram is straightforward but punching in the texts from a screen shot is cumbersome. Please show us what you have tried, including the (unreadable) texts you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parts of your screenshot are unreadable. So I guessed what these may be. Otherwise straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.arrows,fit,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={draw,anchor=center,outer sep=2pt},column sep=9mm,row
sep=1mm] (mat) {
 fft & $\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$ & fft\\
 fft & $\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$ & fft\\
 fft & $\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$ & fft\\
 fft & $\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$ & fft\\[1cm]
 fft & $\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$ & fft\\
};
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (mat-\X-1) -- (mat-\X-2);
\draw[thick,-latex] (mat-\X-3) -- (mat-\X-2);
\draw[thick,latex-] (mat-\X-1) -- ++(-7mm,0) node[left] (L\X) {$a_w^{\X}(t_n)$}
coordinate[xshift=-2cm] (auxL\X);
\draw[thick,latex-] (mat-\X-3) -- ++(7mm,0) node[right] (R\X) {$a_w^{\X}(t_n)$}
coordinate[xshift=2cm] (auxR\X);}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\path (mat-4-\X) -- (mat-5-\X) node[midway]{$\vdots$};}
\foreach \X in {L,R}
{\path (\X4) -- (\X5) node[midway]{$\vdots$};}
\path (auxL1) -- (auxL5) node[midway,align=center] (FLT) {W\\ I\\ N\\ D\\ O\\ W\\ I\\ N\\ G};
\node[fit=(auxL1) (auxL5) (FLT),draw,inner sep=2pt] (FL){};
\path (auxR1) -- (auxR5) node[midway,align=center] (FRT) {W\\ I\\ N\\ D\\ O\\ W\\ I\\ N\\ G};
\node[fit=(auxR1) (auxR5) (FRT),draw,inner sep=2pt] (FR){};
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (FL.east|-L\X) -- (L\X);
\draw[thick,-latex] (FR.west|-R\X) -- (R\X);}
\draw[thick,latex-] (FL.west) -- ++ (-1,0) node[midway,above]{$a(t_n)$};
\draw[thick,latex-] (FR.east) -- ++ (1,0) node[midway,above]{$b(t_n)$};
\node[below=1cm of mat-5-2,draw] (f) {$\aoverbrace[L1R]{CSD}{}(f)$};
\path (mat-5-2.south) -- (f) node[pos=0.4,single arrow,draw,rotate=-90,transform
shape,minimum height=8mm] (ar){};
\draw[-latex,thick,shorten >=8pt] (FL.south) |- (ar.south)
node[pos=0.5,above right]{$P_w$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]